# How to use Auth outside Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have a php script running outside the Laravel 5.2 app I have, and I want to access the Auth:: class from this outer php script. So if the user is logged in the laravel app, he could execute this php file as well.

Could you tell how this could be made?

For now I have this:

```
require __DIR__.'../../../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require __DIR__.'../../../../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->boot();
$app->register(\Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class);
dd($app['auth']);
```

This gives me some auth instance, but not sure what to do with it. I need to have something like:

```
if ($app['auth']::guest()) {
    dd("Go away you guest.");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what you trying to do ? please explain more ?

Comment: I have a laravel 5.2 app. I also have custom filemanager, which is not running inside the laravel app. I want only the authenticated users to have access to the filemanager. I also want to access their info - the name, email, etc..

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do anything in Laravel core file... just add some routes and add `Auth` middleware to your desire route, so Un-Authenticated user will have no access to the mentioned URL

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
 Route::get('dashboard',['as'=>'user-dashboard','uses'=>'Admin\UserController@dashboard']);
});
```

Now using this `middleware'=>'auth'` only loggedin user have access to `Dashboard page`

Comment: No. As I said this filemanager is not part of the laravel app, so I can not use the laravel router to restrict the access. And it is not anly about a restriction, I also want to have the user data.

Comment: If Filemanager is not the part of Laravel App, then how you are trying to use laravel `Auth Class` out of the box ?

Comment: I don't want that, it is an independent application. http://www.responsivefilemanager.com . I know it is possible, I've made it with Laravel 4 with some solutions like this one:  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-use-laravel-authuser-outside-laravel-and-pass-data-in-custom-php

Comment: well, then I dont have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

For 5.7 add below code on the external file:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/appname/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/appname/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```